# ShowDirOnly does not seem to work on Ubuntu 20.04/Qt5

Tags: ubuntu, pyqt5

I'm not sure this is the right forum to ask a Qt question. I'm a Qt beginner and want to popup a dialog to select a folder when a button is pressed. I have a minimal code as below

```
import sys,os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def button_pressed():
    folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select folder",
            os.getcwd(),
            QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly) 

    print(folder)

def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle("Test")
 
    b = QtWidgets.QPushButton(w)
    b.setText("Select folder")
    b.pressed.connect(button_pressed)

    w.show()
 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window()
```

The code is working okay. But the option "ShowDirOnly" seems to be ignored.
[image]
I'm testing this on Ubuntu 20.04. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored"? Can you provide a screenshot of the result? Also, did you try to also add the `DontUseNativeDialog` option?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I went out for the long weekend. Adding DontUseNativeDialog fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I added the screenshot in the original question to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by musicamante, adding DontUseNativeDialog fixed the problem. That is

```
import sys,os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def button_pressed():
    folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select folder",
            os.getcwd(),
            QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly|QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)     
    print(folder)

def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle("Test")
 
    b = QtWidgets.QPushButton(w)
    b.setText("Select folder")
    b.pressed.connect(button_pressed)

    w.show()
 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window()
```

[image]